# Custom Interceptor in Spring Boot [NOT HTTP REQUEST]

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to create multiple custom Interceptor on my Spring Boot Project,
My project based on DDD template and I need for each layer intercept class of this layer to differents actions.
Controler => Http Request and response (I find to intercept this layer)
for next layer I just want to intercept input to
_ Caching
_ Loggin
_ etc...
So input isn't http request so just input params
and I also wnat to cascade multiple iterceptor.
I didn't find cutom inteceptor example that not implement HttpRequest and use in spring boot
Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

you can find exactly what you need at [spring AOP tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop-tutorial/)